# CreateFeatureSelector for nested state (combineReducers)

Tags: angular, state, ngrx, store

The store for the app i am working on looks like this:

```
export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<State> = {
  auth: authReducer,
  settingsSlice: settingsReducer,
  incidentsSlice: incidentListReducer,
  networkStatus: networkStatusReducer,
  incidentSlice: incidentReducer,
};
```

What i am struggling with is creating feature selector for something inside of the incidentSlice, because that slice is very big and has a lot of nested slices.

For example: conferenceCallSlice is within incidentSlice, and i need to select callStatus inside of conferenceCallSlice. So i have tried this, amongst other stuff but i can't get anything to work:

```
export const selectIncidentSlice = createFeatureSelector('incidentSlice');
export const selectConferenceCall = createSelector(selectIncidentSlice, (state: any) => state.conferenceCall);
export const selectConferenceCallConfig = createSelector(selectIncidentSlice, (state: any) => state.conferenceCall.conferenceCall);
export const selectCallStatus = createSelector(selectConferenceCall, (state: any) => state.conferenceCall.callStatus);
```

For reference, this is the IncidentSlice reducer:

```
export interface IncidentState {
  currentIncident: CurrentIncidentState;
  statusBoard: StatusBoardState;
  stakeholders: StakeholderState;
  conferenceCall: ConferenceCallState;
}


export const reducer = combineReducers({
  currentIncident: currentIncidentReducer,
  statusBoard: statusBoardReducer,
  stakeholders: stakeholderReducer,
  conferenceCall: conferenceCallReducer,
});
```

Here is also conferenceCall Reducer:

```
export interface ConferenceCallState {
  conferenceCall: VideoCallRoomConfig;
  callStatus: CallStatus;
}

export const initialState: ConferenceCallState = {
  conferenceCall: conferenceCallConfigData,
  callStatus: CallStatus.NO_CALL,
};
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createFeatureSelector` can only be used for top-level slices from the state tree. In your case,   `auth`,  `settingsSlice`, `incidentsSlice`, `networkStatus`, and `incidentSlice`.

To select state from the `incidentSlice`, the code snippet you shared should be correct (but you don't have to add extra types, these should be inferred.

```
export const selectIncidentSlice = createFeatureSelector<IncidentSliceState>('incidentSlice');
export const selectConferenceCall = createSelector(selectIncidentSlice, (state) => state.conferenceCall);
export const selectConferenceCallConfig = createSelector(selectIncidentSlice, (state) => state.conferenceCall.conferenceCall);
export const selectCallStatus = createSelector(selectConferenceCall, (state => state.conferenceCall.callStatus);
```

If you want that these selectors are generated, take a look at [createFeature](https://ngrx.io/api/store/createFeature)